# Query is slower when using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am running php on my local computer, I also have heidisql on my local computer. I just setup a server on digitalocean, and I have mysql installed on it. When I run I run queries using PHP on my local machine, it takes about `7.81` seconds for the page to run the query. When I copy the queries into heidisql, it takes the same queries `0.141` seconds to run. What would be causing PHP to be slower?

**Note:** Before I switched to digital ocean, the PHP version ran in about `1` second, and the php has not changed.

Here is the PHP that I am running:

```
$db = new Database();

$start = microtime(true);

$db->query("
set @miles = 10;

select
@lat := latitude,
@lon := longitude,
@city := accent,
@country := country,
#@region := region,
@city_id := cc.city_id
from cities cc
inner join countries c on cc.country_id = c.country_id
inner join regions r on cc.region_id = r.region_id and c.country_id = r.country_id
left join locations l on cc.city_id = l.city_id
where city = 'rosemount' and country = 'us' and r.region = 'mn'
limit 1;
");

$cities = $db->getAll("
SELECT c.city_id as id, 
accent as city, 
country as country, 
region, 
latitude, 
longitude,
distance(@lat, @lon, latitude, longitude) as `distance`,
direction(@lat, @lon, latitude, longitude) `direction`
FROM locations l
inner join cities c on l.city_id = c.city_id
inner join regions r on c.region_id = r.region_id
inner join countries cu on c.country_id = cu.country_id
WHERE MBRContains(
    LineString(
        Point(
            @lat + @miles / 68.703, 
            @lon + @miles / (68.703 / COS(RADIANS(@lat)))
        ), 
        Point(
            @lat - @miles / 68.703, 
            @lon - @miles / (68.703 / COS(RADIANS(@lat)))
        )
    ), location)
and l.city_id != @city_id
order By `distance`
");

echo "<p>" . round(microtime(true) - $start, 2) . "</p>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($cities);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Are you connecting to a remote database from your local copy?

Comment: Yes I am, but would that matter? Its fast in one app and slow in the other...

Comment: I have restarted mysql, and now the page errors out from a long page load, but heidisql is still running the queries in less than a second. Why?

Comment: I found it is PDO that is causing the problem, because when I try using `mysql_query` it runs in about `0.36` seconds...

Comment: Fixed the PDO Part! I split the queries up instead of doing 2 queries in one PDO command I now do one per command and that speeds it up to the speed of heidisql!